# CURL FTPS failure (InitializeSecurityContext)

Tags: ssl, curl

Using Curl 7.55.1 on Windows 10 attempting to confirm an FTPS server is using TLSv1.2. (If there's a better/easier way to do this, feel free to let me know)

I am running the command `curl -v --insecure --tlsv1.2 ftps://[server:port]` and receive the following response:

```
*   Trying [server]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to [server] ([server]) port [port] (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with [server] port [port] (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: using IP address, SNI is not supported by OS.
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 156 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 156 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with [server] port [port] (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 527
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 527 length 4096
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with [server] port [port]
* schannel: clear security context handle
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid
```

Comment: "schannel: using IP address, SNI is not supported by OS."  this is probably first problem to solve. Also did you try other clients, like `wget` or `openssl s_client`? Your question is not really ontopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: I had tried other clients, but wasn't sure how to verify the level of SSL. I downloaded Wireshark and ran my code locally twice (with TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 respectively) against an FTP server I knew was only accepting TLS1.2 connections, and then parsed the packets to find the instance of failure for 1.1 and the successful handshake for 1.2.  I originally had this information from running with the -Djavax.net.debug=ssl parameter, but at that time the server was accepting both levels, and I was unsure if the response from the server was the actual SSL level, or just parroting the value I provided.